# How to get Azure SQL transactional log

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

How to get the transaction logs for a Azure SQL db? I'm trying to find log from portal of azure but not getting any luck.

If there is no way to get the log where that is saying in Microsoft docs. any help is appriciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure SQL Database auditing tracks database events and writes them to an audit log in your Azure storage account, or sends them to Event Hub or Log Analytics for downstream processing and analysis.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/audit-log-format)

**Blob audit**

Audit logs stored in Azure Blob storage are stored in a container named sqldbauditlogs in the Azure storage account. The directory hierarchy within the container is of the form ////. The Blob file name format is _.xel, where CreationTime is in UTC hh_mm_ss_ms format, and FileNumberInSession is a running index in case session logs spans across multiple Blob files.

For example, for database Database1 on Server1 the following is a possible valid path:

Server1/Database1/SqlDbAuditing_ServerAudit_NoRetention/2019-02-03/12_23_30_794_0.xel

Read-only Replicas audit logs are stored in the same container. The directory hierarchy within the container is of the form ////RO/. The Blob file name shares the same format. The Audit Logs of Read-only Replicas are stored in the same container.

Comment: [Transactional log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) != audit log

Comment: @LukaszSzozda not directly but you will get the transaction as well there

Answer (score 1):

You don't as it is not exposed in the service.  Please step back and describe what problem you'd like to solve.  If you want a DR solution, for example, then active geo-replication can solve this for you as part of the service offering.

The log format in Azure SQL DB is constantly changing and is "ahead" of the most recent version of SQL Server.  So, it is probably not useful to expose the log (the format is not documented).  Your use case will likely determine the alternative question you can ask instead.